# C# MD5 Hash results not expected result

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5

I've tried every example I can find on the web but I cannot get my .NET code to produce the same MD5 Hash results from my VB6 app.

The VB6 app produces identical results to this site:
http://www.functions-online.com/md5.html

But I cannot get the same results for the same input in C# (using either the MD5.ComputeHash method or the FormsAuthentication encryption method)

Please help!!!!

As requested, here is some code. This is pulled straight from MSDN:

```
    public string hashString(string input)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string.
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

My test string is:

QWERTY123TEST

The results from this code is:

```
8c31a947080131edeaf847eb7c6fcad5
```

The result from Test MD5 is:

```
f6ef5dc04609664c2875895d7da34eb9
```

Note: The result from the TestMD5 is what I am expecting

Note: I've been really, really stupid, sorry - just realised I had the wrong input. As soon as I hard-coded it, it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: How do you compare hash results? Do you compare 32 characters string representations?

Comment: Post some code so we can see if there's an issue in the way you're computing the hash, or if there's something wrong with the way you're supplying data to the hashing algorithms.

Comment: using `Encoding.Default.` may create problems because if you change the system encoding or the machine it might create different results, use UTF8 for stability...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a C# MD5 method that i know works, i have used it to authenticate via different web restful APIs

```
   public static string GetMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        return s.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't produce the same results as the  http://www.functions-online.com/md5.html website though.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong - it seems to produce exactly the same results. I would suggest you check your whitespace and character set - you are most likely inserting something like an extra new line, or you are using unicode characters that are being treated differently by the online form (either treated with a different encoding, or are being dropped entirely)

Comment: Perhaps you are appending a line terminator?  Perhaps you are mangling the input by passing binary data through a UTF-8 encoder?  I did check the functions-online site and pass in a test vector of one value -- MD5("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72 which it does compute correctly.

Answer (score 2):

What makes the "functions-online" site (http://www.functions-online.com/md5.html) an authority on MD5?  For me, it works OK only for ISO-8859-1. But when I try pasting anything other than ISO-8859-1 into it, it returns the same MD5 hash.  Try Cyrillic capital B by itself, code point 0x412.  Or try Han Chinese symbol for water, code point 0x98A8.
As far as I know, the posted C# applet is correct.